# Getter method must return a double - how to implement DecimalFormat?

Tags: java, double, getter, pojo, decimalformat

I need the getter to return a double to .2 decimal spaces...

```
public double getPrice () {

   double totalPrice = 0.00;
   DecimalFormat deciFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```

...

```
return Double.valueOf(deciFormat.format(totalPrice));
```

but when I check the result in my .jsp it's still only to 1 decimal space. Any and all insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're confusing number with a string representation of it. If the method returns a double, the string representation you create has little to do with the "significant" bits of the number returned.

Comment: Return it as a String

Comment: Store it as a BigDecimal and return it as a String.

Comment: When i make the return type for the method a String from double now get a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError :/

Comment: Usually, that error means you're running different code from what you've got in your source files.  Maybe an earlier version of something.  Make sure you rebuild everything.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem THANKS! did a "Clean & Build" and issue was solved! Kudos

Comment: There is no such thing as `a getter to return a double to .2 decimal spaces'. See the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the method return type to a String.
Did a "Clean and build" and String.Format did the job!

Comment: Just remember, every time you store an amount of money in a `double`, a kitten dies.